# Moving the entities in Phoria.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, phoria.js

I am trying to make a game in which ball gets bounced and fall into a bin. The position of the bin to appear is random. Is there a way I can move my ball entity to jump and land based on the dynamic coordinates of bin. If suppose I know the direction and distance of the bin, how can I make the ball to move such that it appears that ball falling into the bin. In Three.js, this was achieved by changing position.x, position.y and position.z. How to achieve this in phoria.js?

Also is there a way to increase the rendering speed?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the rendering speed setting a lower Timeout:

```
var requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                       window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
                       function(c) {window.setTimeout(c, X)};
```

Just decreased the value of X, so you'll get a higher rendering speed.

To move the ball, make sure you have variables for the coordinate positions, so you just have to translate the ball in the main animation loop:

```
   var fnAnimate = function() {
      if (!pause)
      {
         ball.translateX (deltaX);
         ball.translateY (deltaY);
         ball.translateZ (deltaZ);

         cube.rotateY(0.5*Phoria.RADIANS);
         scene.modelView();
         renderer.render(scene);
      }
      requestAnimFrame(fnAnimate);
      input();
   };
```

And make shure your input functions alterate this variable, somehow.